React + Bootstrap 5.3 : how to apply conditional CSS selector override on Bootstrap's SASS variables?
TLDR: I want to change Bootstrap SASS variable value depending on a CSS selector
PS. I know I can manually assign the color directly but I'm trying to understand how to override Bootstrap CSS properties by using the SASS variables in combination with CSS selectors.

example (contents of Apps.scss from the link below)
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";

//the 2  lines below work but both H3 text color are the same
$headings-color: blue; //this works
$body-color: green; //works too if you comment out headings-color

h3.red {
  $headings-color: red; //does not work
}

h3.blue {
  $headings-color: blue; //does not work
}

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";


Here's the link to the sample code that might better explain what I want (might need to click the refresh button on the preview tab to get it to work) => click here for codesandbox.io
Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Use "!global" after colors and before ";". It should then override the global variable with the tagged one.
Edit: Turns out this solution does not work as it overrides the default any way. It is not conditional. :(

does not work. Thanks for trying.

nevermind. you are right, It does not work

SASS variables are used by SASS code. If you simply re-declare a global variable within a block and don't use its value, nothing will happen. So you need to add some CSS properties that can use this re-declared variable.
For example:
h3.red {
  $headings-color: red;
  color: $headings-color;
}

h3.blue {
  $headings-color: blue;
  color: $headings-color;
}

Think of this code as a preprocessor instruction. This means that selectors h1.red and h1.blue will be created, containing only what was written in the corresponding SCSS blocks.
This is the output CSS code that will be used by the browser:
h3.red {
  color: red;
}

h3.blue {
  color: blue;
}

In your case, the resulting CSS will be empty, because the SCSS code doesn't contain any CSS properties:
// code generated by your SCSS code
h3.red {
}

h3.blue {
}

// here is the code generated by bootstrap/scss/bootstrap
// ...


To change the color in real-time you can use CSS variables (aka custom properties). You can check the list of Bootstrap CSS variables. Here is the example:
h3.red {
  --bs-heading-color: red;
}

h3.blue {
  --bs-heading-color: blue;
}


if that's the case, then why is it working for the 2 cases above?

Because in those lines you redefine the global variables that will be used in bootstrap SCSS code. But when you define local variables in your blocks, it won’t exist outside those blocks

Again: think of this code as a preprocessor instruction. You probably expect that all SASS variables will exist in the resulting CSS code, but that’s not true. In other words, SASS variables don’t exist in the browser. You didn't ask how to change the color, but if that's the case, you need to change the CSS (not SASS) variable for a particular selector. For example, "--bs-body-color: red" or something like that.

I've added the example of using CSS variables in the answer above. I hope it will help to feel the difference between SASS and CSS code
